# How to replace a list of characters in a string with a corresponding list of characters

Tags: javascript

In a string like

```
"this is a sample string"
```

How could I replace a list of characters like

```
['t', 'h', 's', 'g']
```

with a corresponding list of characters like

```
['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'K']
```

**in  a fast way**, and get this result:

```
"XYiZ iZ a Zample ZXrinK"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code and let us see where you get stucked.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"this is a sample string".replace(/t|h|s|g/g, function(v) {
    var map = {t: 'X', h: 'Y', s: 'Z', g: 'K'}
    return map[v];
}); //output XYiZ iZ a Zample ZXrinK
```

Note: you can make it faster by:

- saving the regexp into a variable instead of recreating the regexp every time you replace.
- saving the map into a variable outside the replace, so you don't recreate the map every time the replace fire the function

Comment: Very wise approach indeed.

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
        public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                char[] original={'t', 'h', 's', 'g'};
                char[] replace ={'T', 'H', 'S', 'G'};

                String inputString= "this is a sample string";
                for(int i=0;i<original.length;i++){
                    if(inputString.contains(original[i]+"")){
                        inputString=inputString.replaceAll(original[i]+"", replace[i]+"");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(inputString);
            }


        }
```

**Output:**  THiS iS a Sample STrinG

Answer (score 0):

```
function mapReplace(str, map) {
    return str.split('').reduce(function(acc, c) {
        acc.push(map[c] === undefined ? c : map[c]);
        return acc;
    }, []).join('');
}

//returns 'XYiZ iZ a Zample ZXrinK'
mapReplace("this is a sample string", {t: 'X', h: 'Y', s: 'Z', g: 'K'});
```

<strike>This alternative should be faster than a regex approach.</strike>

After actually running benchmarks, it is clear that regex replace beats this approach 4 to 1:

- RegExp x 325,181 ops/sec ±0.46% (96 runs sampled)
- MapReplace# x 84,956 ops/sec ±0.36% (97 runs sampled)